# Get html inner text by id

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I wanna get innertext or even better innerhtml from down `li` class.

In normal desktop version it works.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q6Te5.png]

but the same code wont work on WP8 because wp8 doesnt have all features.i serch all over the internet and i finde just codes for desktop or codes which doesn't work soo.

```
HtmlElement e1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(textBox2.Text);
string content = e1.InnerText;
textBox1.Text = content;
```

There is HTML form which I wanna get the same result like I get it with "desktop" version of c#

```
<li id="ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_lstvAlphabet_listRestaurants_0_lstvRestaurant_0_liItem_0" class="restaurantItem" sssp:rs="2;7;8;10;" sssp:rl="Ljubljana" sssp:rn=""Celica hostel"">

    <div class="name">
        <h1>
        <h2>(Metelkova 8, Ljubljana)</h2>
        <span class="blocked"></span>
        <span class="blocked"> </span>
    </div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>
    <div class="prices">
        <p>
            <span>Vrednost doplacila:</span>
            <strong>3,15 EUR</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Vrednost obroka:</span>
            <strong>5,78 EUR</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="features">
        <img id="ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_lstvAlphabet_listRestaurants_0_lstvRestaurant_0_lstvFeatures_0_imgFeature_0" title="Celiakiji prijazni obroki" alt="Celiakiji prijazni obroki" src="/App_Themes/SOS/images/icncoeliac.png">
        <img id="ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_lstvAlphabet_listRestaurants_0_lstvRestaurant_0_lstvFeatures_0_imgFeature_1" title="Solatni bar" alt="Solatni bar" src="/App_Themes/SOS/images/icnsaladbar.png">
        <img id="ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_lstvAlphabet_listRestaurants_0_lstvRestaurant_0_lstvFeatures_0_imgFeature_2" title="Stalen arhitektonsko prilagojen dostop za invalide in dostop do mize v notranjosti lokala ter do toalete prilagojene za invalide" alt="Stalen arhitektonsko prilagojen dostop za invalide in dostop do mize v notranjosti lokala ter do toalete prilagojene za invalide" src="/App_Themes/SOS/images/icnwheelchairwc.png">
        <img id="ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_lstvAlphabet_listRestaurants_0_lstvRestaurant_0_lstvFeatures_0_imgFeature_3" title="Kosila" alt="Kosila" src="/App_Themes/SOS/images/icnlunch.png">
    </div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: "wont work" is not very clear explanation of a problem. Also please inline content of your links into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with the WebBrowser control, but if all you need is retrieving the content on an HTML element, you can just retrieve the HTML with a normal WebRequest and then use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML.